# Анимация в веб-дизайне(новичек)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго всем.
Я в веб-дизайне без году неделя. Два дня игрался, копируя шапку из одного сайта. И то вышло не до конца. Надеюсь вы поможете прояснить вопрос, который меня интерисует. Как сделать анимацию при наведении, как у значков соц. сетей в левом верхнем углу и индикатор меню. Я так понимаю, это нужно как-то в Js извращаться (там вообще не ступала нога меня), или можно все html-css обрисовать? 
С-венно ссылка : http://www.kriesi.at/themes/eunoia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В интернете полным полно разных туториалов по css-анимациям. Вот, к примеру, хороший ресурс http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations/
А это решение именно вашего вопроса:

```css
body{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.icon{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #a7a7a7;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.icon .fa{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.icon:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.icon:hover{
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
.icon:hover:after{
  background-color: #e44885;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" />

<a href="#" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Когда интересно, как свёрстан какой-нибудь элемент на странице, можно просмотреть его код и разметку. (Например, в Chrome и подобных браузерах для этого в контекстном меню есть пункт «Просмотреть код элемента» или подобный.) Таким образом, можно быстро научиться эффектам, интересным конкретно для Вас. Всё, что пока неизвестно, элементарно отыскивается в поисковике.

Для анимации нужного элемента страницы (без использования скриптов) по наведению курсора пишется CSS-разметка для псевдокласса :hover этого элемента. По сути там всего лишь меняются некоторые параметры (например, цвет фона, толщина границ, местоположение, возможно, лёгкий поворот или масштаб...) и задаётся свойство transition-duration с нужной длительностью плавного перехода.

В общем, пробуйте, там всё просто.